# How to process this json-response in RxJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, rxjs

I have angular2 app (TypeScript), which uses RxJS to process json-request (I know about angular's services, I have just simplified code).

This code is in class method:

```
this.http.post(url, body, options)
                    .map(
                        response => response.json()
                    )
                    .subscribe(result => {
                        persons => this.persons = persons
                    });
```

In class I have field `persons` and I want that this field should get data from response in order to use this `persons` in `*ngFor`

Also I have java-backend, which produces such response (I have got this output after adding `console.log()` in `map()`):

```
message:"[{"personId":"29d5a903-b664-4fc3-9bd9-0836f1b3dc58","email":"test@example.com","firstname":"Test","lastname":"Testoff","username":"oooo","birthdate":"2000-05-28","gender":"male","password":"xxxxx","active":null,"profiles":[]}]"
```

What am I doing wrong ? (I'm backender, sorry, for silly questions, may be)

Comment: What is `response.json()`? Are you sure it returns a string? `result => {
                        persons => this.persons = persons
                    }` --- this does not look syntactically correct as well.

Comment: I have fixed code, it was for debug to define what's wrong sorry.
"syntactically correct " - TypeScript thinks that it's OK, also, pls, check here https://plnkr.co/edit/r1QFQj0wZ5hgJxrsRoGF?p=preview

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ --- try `const foo = () => { foo => 2; };`  and see what it translates it to. It translates it to an anonymous function that is not invoked, hence it's a no-op. PS: yep, it is *syntactically* correct, my bad, still - logically it's wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you fixed the code and it is working. I'd like to outline a different solution which is more aligned with angular2's philosophy, do not hold a local variable in your app, use directly the service's sequence:

```
<my-person 
    *ngFor="let person; of peopleService.people | async;" 
    [name]="person.name"
    (hello)="saidHello($event)">
  </my-person>
```